# Disabling Javascript expanders on Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, function, expander

I am very new to Javascript and I'm using an expander while designing a mobile site. The script looks like this:

```
$(function () {

    $('.expander .details').hide();
    $('.expander .trigger').

    click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().slideToggle().parent().toggleClass("open");
    });

    $('button#expandAll').click(function (e) {
        $('.expander .details').slideDown().parent().addClass("open");
    });

    $('button#collapseAll').click(function (e) {
        $('.expander .details').slideUp().parent().removeClass("open");
    });
});
```

What I want to do is disable the expander when the site width reaches above 600px. I have tried the window resize but I can't figure out the correct syntax. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? I'd suggest to use media queries with `.details { display:block; }`

Comment: Yeah, normally you'd hide or replace the trigger element rather than monkeying with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

```
if($(document).width() > 600) {
    $('.expander .trigger').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().slideToggle().parent().toggleClass("open");
    });
} else {
    $('.expander .trigger').hide();
}
```